# Firebase 3.0 iOS Codelab Chat App tutorial with Swift

Tags: ios, database, xcode, swift, firebase

Check this link: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/#2

This is a tutorial to teach how to use Firebase 3.0 but I got some errors at the very beginning, at the step 3 named "3. Build the starter app". It is said:
To build the starter app:
 1. Run pod update
 2. Open the FriendlyChatSwift.xcworkspace file to open the project in Xcode.
 3. Click the Run button. You should see the Friendly Chat home screen appear after a few seconds.

But xCode show me 7 errors and when I run my app: "Build Failed". So I tried to go through the next steps, until the step 5 and xCode still shows errors. Could you please help? Thanks!
[Click to see my xCode screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3q80.jpg)

Comment: Uck compiler segfaults are the worst. Which version of XCode are you on? Try cleaning the build directory to see if that helps at all (hold option, Product > Clean)

Comment: Yes I did the Clean but doesn't fix it. Did you try out https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/ and you don't have such error ?

Answer (score 0):

One reason might be that you used the FriendlyChatSwift.**xcodeproj** instead of opening FriendlyChatSwift.**xcworkspace** which will appear after updating the pod and make sure you exited Xcode while updating pod.

Comment: This was already done! Unfortunately, this is not the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add your googleservice-info.plist. you can get that from the Firebase dashboard.

Comment: This was already done! Unfortunately, this is not the reason.